# Increasing scale of an object with Cloth Pressure enabled causes object to fly away

Tags: cloth-simulation

As the title states: increasing the scale of an object will send it flying away with all of the settings being identical and scale applied.

1.Before scale[image]

2. After [image]

*Please ignore different Bending number on the second screen I was just trying different settings before taking that screenshot